# Save array of string to IndexedDB and get value from IndexedDB and save to array of string

Tags: angular, typescript, indexeddb

I try this:

`

```
saveTasksList() {
    this.storage.setItem('tasks', this.tasksList).subscribe( () => {}, () => {});
  }
  loadTasksList() {
      this.tasksList = JSON.stringify(this.storage.getItem('tasks'));
  }
```

`

,but:

[**ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(42,7): error TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQvEG.png)

all code: https://pastebin.com/qfTLdRGd

Comment: can you add more code and with error screenshot. Describe where the error is and so on

Comment: I did it, and ?

Comment: change the line 41 as `this.tasksList = <string[]>JSON.parse(this.storage.getItem('tasks'));`